# Meteor server method run time

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I tried to find what in my application that takes so much CPU usage and why I get so long waiting times so I started to log some stuff in my application. When I logged every part in my application I ran into this:

```
var updateTime = process.hrtime();

Nightclubs.update({_id: nightclubId}, {$push: { guests: {
  value: value,
  currentGuestAmount: currentGuestAmount+value,
  date: thisEntryDate.toDate(),
  gender: gender,
  age: age,
  guard: guardId
}}})

var updateDiff = process.hrtime(updateTime);
```

Later in the method I log this time like this:

```
console.log('update benchmark took %d nanoseconds', updateTime[0] * 1e9 + updateTime[1]);
```

Which result in this:

```
update benchmark took 1084353904561267 nanoseconds
```

Yep.. That is 1.8 WEEKS.... This is really weird since the method in total takes 916589992 nanoseconds, or 0.91 seconds (which still is a bit too long)

Does any one have any clue about this?

PS, A bit of details on what data I insert:

```
guests: { type: Array, defaultValue: [] },
'guests.$': { type: Object },
'guests.$.value': { type: Number },
'guests.$.currentGuestAmount': { type: Number },
'guests.$.date': { type: Date },
'guests.$.age': { type: Number },
'guests.$.gender': { type: String },
'guests.$.guard': { type: String },
```

Comment: You may want to use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Timers

Comment: @Ser Yeah, that one gave a bit better answer: 15ms! I think I'll continue with that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude, use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` instead of `process.hrtime()`

```
console.time("Update nightclub");

Nightclubs.update({_id: nightclubId}, {$push: { guests: {
  value: value,
  currentGuestAmount: currentGuestAmount+value,
  date: thisEntryDate.toDate(),
  gender: gender,
  age: age,
  guard: guardId
}}})

console.timeEnd("Update nightclub");
```